# Where to save the JWT Token in Laravel

Tags: rest, laravel, cookies, jwt

Well i have a scenario where i have a rest api built on laravel and controlled by JWT. Then i use another route to request the api for the token. But once i receive the token after giving the login credentials where should i save the token?

I think it should be saved in the client's browser, so on the next request we just fetch the token from the browser and then go through another request. Saving the token in the browser will also give the advantage with scaling the server, because if its on the server's session not all the servers will be in sync with this session data.

**Now i want your opinion on this, should i store the token in a cookie or in the browser's LocalStorage? I know how to store it in cookie but dont know how to store in localstorage with js. It would be helpful if you could point out to any tutorial for this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good article [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/) on local storage vs cookies with JWT. They recommend cookies because of XSS vulnerabilities when using local storage.

It is also worth pointing out that if you are using the [Laravel JWT Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package, that the token is still being stored on the server (using Laravel's cache system) by default, and so will not scale across servers. You should be able to change this with the [`storage`](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/master/src/config/config.php#L160) config option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and using a cookie is indeed what i am going to do. Do you know of any tutorial or code that actually shows how to properly make the request from php instead of a js framework

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Presumably you are using JWT to statelessly authenticate a js web app? If this is the case you self-evidently have to request and store the token using the js app. What js framework are you using?

Comment: Well the point is that i dont want to use a js framework and i am now looking into guzzle which is an http client, so it has the options to send headers and cookies with every requests.

Comment: If your app is a regular, server side, Laravel app, then why bother with JWT? You could just use the out of the box Laravel auth.

Comment: Well actually i wanted to make it scalable, out of the box laravel auth stores data with sessions and sessions are saved on the server.

Comment: Sessions are only saved to the server if using the `file` session driver. You could easily switch to database or redis sessions for scalabilty. If you're not storing the sessions in the browser, you're going to have to store session data somewhere, whether it be a token or a session payload.

Comment: @omerFarooq I am actually in the same boat here and I am a little confused as to why there's no examples showing a php-to-php use of JWT. I am trying to leverage JWT to allow two separate servers to communicate via a secure API. They are two separate apps on two servers. I will also be using a js-framework for my front-end but a lot of my api communications is being done via jobs and automation where no end-user is involved. Is using JWT not correct for this use-case? If you've found an example that helped you along I would love to see it. Thanks

Comment: @vesperknight Well i didn't find the answer at that time due to limited documentation, so i just went with the default laravel Authentication. And i am glad that i went with the default option. For a small highly interactive application, which might use angular or backbone JWT is great. But for larger applications its just a pain. Anyways if you want to use JWT for PHP to PHP then you can do it through the php-jwt package. Here is a great tutorial with detailed information on the insides (highly recommended)
http://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/

Comment: And here is another one http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-api-only-jwt-powered-laravel-app/

Comment: "that the token is still being stored on the server " - JWT token are stateless, they are not stored on the server.